# How to get available fonts style of a given font

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create 2 combo boxes. First combo with all fonts installed in windows, second one with available font styles based on the selected font in the first combo box.

I've got all installed fonts using `EnumFontFamiliesEx` function but I can't figure out where to find all available font styles for a give font.

I don't want to use `CFontDialog`

Any ideas?

Comment: All fonts support all styles because the font manager will synthesize them if needed.

Comment: I'm agree with you but, I am looking at Notepad fonts and some fonts have different fonts style. For e.g if you are looking at font "Consolas" you will find font styles(Regular, Italic, Bold, Bold Italic). If you are looking at font "MS Gothic" you will find font styles (Regular, Oblique, Bold, Bold Oblique) and so on... Some fonts have only 2 fonts style..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this, so consider this an educated guess.

You initially call EnumFontFamilies with a null pointer for lpszFamily (which the docs now sometimes incorrectly call lpLogfont).  That gives you one representative font from each font family (e.g., Arial).

Once the user selects a family, you use EnumFontFamilies again, this time with the name of that family.  That should then enumerate all of the font files that belong to that font family.  The NEWTEXTMETRIC object passed to the enumeration callback can be inspected to see if it's bold, italic, etc.

Be aware that for the NEWTEXTMETRIC, you might get a pointer to just a TEXTMETRIC.  I'm not sure how you're supposed to know whether the extra fields are there or not.

You might be able to do this with EnumFontFamiliesEx (note the -Ex suffix) as well.  The docs have a table telling you what will be enumerated depending on what constraints you put in the LOGFONT.  The callback for EnumFontFamiliesEx also gives the elfFullName field, which should give the name of the font with the particular style it supports (e.g., "Arial Black").  Note that these names are in ANSI, even if you use the wide ("Unicode") version of the API.

Comment: Exactly! I called EnumFontFamilies for get all fonts installed and on combo box selection I called again EnumFontFamilies and pass the name of the selected font. But, I saw another problem here. Some fonts have only "Regular" or "Regular Bold". I checked in Notepad fonts and they have all font styles. For e.g. in my app, when I do a selection on "MS Config" font I've got only "Regular". On the notepad font dialog, they have "Regular, Oblique, Bold and Bold Oblique". Do you have any idea why EnumFontFamilies don't find all fonts styles?

Comment: I don't have MS Config, so I can't do an exact comparison to what you're seeing.  I assume Notepad is showing all styles, including those it can simulate from the native ones.  EnumFontFamilies is returning only the native ones (which I thought is what you wanted).  The Fonts control panel applet shows five faces for Arial.  Notepad shows those five plus Black Oblique, which I assume is simulated by setting a slant angle on Arial Black.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't "MS Config". Idk why I said that... It was "MS Gothic"

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends what do you want to do with this enumerated results. If you want to filter out simulated faces and just get a list, I suggest to look at DirectWrite, where simulated faces are explicitly marked as such.

If you want to be able to make a selection from this dialog and use that to render with GDI, it's also possible to tell if simulation happened, but not in a documented API way.

Comment: I want to make a selection and return the font name and font style selected by user. [link](https://imgur.com/hHhIEMP) i want to do a dialog like this but I don't know how to get all available font styles of a font.