# Best way to Pursue Enumerating Fonts

Tags: fonts

Self-taught VB hack here with just a little .net experience. Most of the posts I find on this subject are fairly old, so I'm looking for the best direction to pursue before I start down any one particular rabbit hole, and to make sure there isn't something new I'm missing.

I've written an app in vb.net that loads and unloads fonts. I'm reading the registry to see what fonts are loaded, reading the font info directly from the font files and using AddFontResource, RemoveFontResource and modifying the registry for when the machine is restarted.

All of that works, but as [this astute post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940407/checking-if-a-postscript-font-is-installed/20010236#20010236) points out, just because it's in the registry doesn't mean it's enumerating. We store our production fonts on a network drive and Windows 10 is terrible at reconnecting after a restart/logon, so I've done a fair amount of research on enumerating all the fonts loaded and, amazingly, there doesn't seem to be anything that readily works.

The use of the EnumFontFamiliesEx API is pretty much mind boggling to me (just due to my lack of knowledge) and even the code I've [downloaded](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680732-List-all-fonts-on-the-current-system) works relatively well but doesn't get some of the fonts that are loaded. Same as the OP of that link, I've not figured out why, at least not yet. I've modified that downloaded code to use EnumFontFamiliesExW API as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702157/get-list-of-fonts-win32/2702205#2702205), but there were still fonts missing.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100641/how-to-get-available-fonts-style-of-a-given-font/55107052#55107052) suggested something called DirectWrite which I THINK is part of DirectX? After looking at that for a few the frustration level landed me here.

So, I think, two questions:

1. (the biggie) Is there something newer than EnumFontFamiliesExW?
2. For the OTF and TTF fonts I'm reading the "Typographic Family name" (ID 16 as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name)), when it's available, because that's what Adobe Products display. Is this ID even readable using EnumFontFamiliesExW? I've not seen anything to indicate it is.

Yikes, sorry so long and thanks for reading if you made it this far!

Answer (score 6):

### Quick answers

> (the biggie) Is there something newer than EnumFontFamiliesExW?

Yes: DirectWrite.

> For the OTF and TTF fonts I'm reading the "Typographic Family name" (ID 16 as defined here), when it's available, because that's what Adobe Products display. Is this ID even readable using EnumFontFamiliesExW? I've not seen anything to indicate it is.

The quick answer is No, GDI doesn't give you name IDs 16/17. DWrite does, though in some cases the nature of the font might require you to call a certain way. This is actually somewhat complicated to explain completely. I'm going to give you some comprehensive info, but for this in particular, jump down to Font family models.

Now, your question also seemed to have an aspect of certain fonts not enumerating when you expect them to enumerate. It's hard to comment on that, certainly not without more details.

### Windows font APIs

Windows has three different generations of text/font platform APIs: GDI, GDI+ and DirectWrite. For your purposes, we can ignore GDI+.

There's also WPF, which is part of .Net. .Net isn't part of Windows *proper*, and the functionality is basically a subset of D(irect)Write, so I'll mostly skip that as well, except for a historical point below.

Both GDI and DWrite have APIs to enumerate fonts that are loaded into the OS session. Now, there are some things to understand:

### Installed vs. loaded

When GDI is initialized during boot, it doesn't have any fonts.* It only acquires fonts when another part of the OS starts calling [`AddFontResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew) or [`AddFontResourceEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourceexw). That other part of the OS reads the `Fonts` key in the registry and calls one of those APIs for each entry.

(* Not 100% true: On its own, GDI initially reads reg entries under the HKLM...\GRE_Initialize key to load certain bitmap fonts.)

But note that any app can also call `AddFontResource()`.

So, a font is "loaded" in GDI after the font file has been passed in a call to `AddFontResource()`. The notion of "installed font" is appropriately applied to fonts registered in the registry that will get loaded automatically on boot.

Note that there's also the [`RemoveFontResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-removefontresourcew) / [`RemoveFontResourceEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-removefontresourceexw) functions. So, a font that is *installed* could, at some point during the use session, get unloaded.

The same concepts basically apply to DWrite. It reads the registry to load fonts (rather than waiting on something else to load them). It also talks with GDI to keep in sync in terms of what fonts are loaded. It supports loading additional fonts, but only for the calling app. So, if your intent is loading fonts for use in any app, a way hasn't (yet) be provided to do that.

### System vs. user

Another thing that might be useful to know is that Windows 10 supports a distinction between fonts that are installed or loaded *system wide* versus *per user*. Fonts that are installed system-wide are registered in the `HKLM` hive in the registry and (by default) stored in the %windir%\Fonts folder. Per-user fonts are registered in the `HKCU` (current user) hive in the registry and stored at a location within the %userprofile%\AppData folder.

When you get an enumeration of fonts from GDI or from DWrite, it will include the (currently loaded) system-wide fonts as well as fonts for that user.

### All apps / one app / not-enumerated

Normally when fonts are loaded in GDI, they can be enumerated and used by any app. But `AddFontResourceEx()` adds flags that can be used to limit that:

- `FR_PRIVATE`: only the app that loaded the font can use it.
- `FR_NOT_ENUM`: the font is never enumerated, even for the app that loaded it.

DWrite, supports the idea of app-specific fonts, and has more capabilities around that than GDI. For example, it provides a way that an app can load its fonts directly from a cloud service. But the fonts are only ever available for the one app. DWrite has some different APIs for these kinds of scenarios; the differences have to do with concepts of "collections" and "sets". (Font collections were the earliest design, but font sets were added later to provide certain additional capabilities.) If the DWrite APIs for per-app fonts are of interest, there's a [code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DirectWriteCustomFontSets) that demonstrates using the APIs for some different scenarios.

### GDI vs. DWrite: C vs. COM

I've described some similarities and some differences between GDI and DWrite. Another important difference is that the GDI APIs are "flat" C APIs. DWrite (like all of DirectX) uses COM. The COM APIs aren't difficult to use, but if you come from the older Win32 world it just looks a little different.

With GDI, there are lots of functions, and you just call whatever function whenever. (In some cases, you may need to call one API to get a handle before you can call another, but it has a "procedural" feel.)

With DWrite, there is only one *function*: [`DWriteCreateFactory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-dwritecreatefactory). You call that function to get a "factory" object, and from you use its methods to get other objects that support particular *interfaces*. Also, the interfaces are versioned (e.g., `IDWriteFactory` vs. `IDWriteFactory1`... vs. `IDWriteFactory7`). The objects are always able to support the most recent interface version, but initially they may present only an older interface, and you have to use a COM technique to get the newer interface. (It's very much like getting an object of a parent class and then casting it to a subclass.)

### Types of fonts

Another difference has to do with types of fonts supported. GDI supports

- legacy bitmap fonts
- legacy stroke fonts
- legacy "Postscript" Type 1 fonts
- TrueType / OpenType fonts -- except for some newer capabilities

DWrite supports

- legacy bitmap fonts
- TrueType / OpenType fonts -- including newer capabilities

In recent years, the OpenType format has been extended to support color fonts, and variable fonts. GDI does not support color fonts, and has limitations in its support for variable fonts. DWrite doesn't have those limitations.

### Font family models

As you can tell from the name of the GDI function, fonts have a notion of "family". For example, "Arial" is a family; "Arial Regular" and "Arial Italic" are two faces within that family.

One of the things that makes `EnumFontFamiliesEx()` a bit complicated is that it enumerates both the families and also the faces within a family. DWrite also has APIs that organize fonts into that two-level hierarchy as well, but it's a bit clearer because it has distinct interfaces for the family level (font family) versus the face level (font / fontface).

Now, the question arises: how is a family defined? You're probably familiar with apps that have Arial as a font option in a dropdown, say, and the B(old) and I(talic) buttons. So, that's presenting fonts with a certain family model: a family can have Regular, Bold, Italic and Bold Italic faces.

But that's never been how type designers think about families. They think of families as maybe including Light or Semibold or Heavy; or Condensed or Ultra-condensed or Extended; or Title vs. Caption vs.... In a typographic sense, a family might include any number of different face styles.

The Regular/Bold/Italic/Bold Italic model is sometimes referred to as a "GDI family model", though GDI isn't quite so limited. Rather, it's apps written on GDI that created that limitation. That forced font designers to create fonts in a way that could fit into that model.

That is what name IDs 1 and 2 do: they are the name IDs that GDI uses to decide what's a family and what's a "sub-family" (a style/face within the family). Font developers long ago got into the practice of limiting those strings to fit in the R/B/I/BI model.

But designers didn't want to be limited to that model. So, name IDs 16 and 17 were added: they were intended to allow font developers to organize families as they want, without constraints. This is what Adobe apps support.

Now along the way WPF was introduced. And it was being developed about the same time that CSS2 was in development. In CSS2, font properties `font-weight`, `font-stretch` and `font-style` were introduced, which comprise three independent axes on which fonts within a family might differ. There was also the `font-variant` property that was added, but it fit better into OpenType's notion of *font features*, not a family style axis. So, WPF APIs were designed to support a family model with weight, stretch and style axes.

And when DWrite was first introduced, it did the same. So, in DWrite, the IDWriteFontCollection interface assumes that, e.g., "Arial", "Arial Narrow", "Arial Bold", "Arial Black" fit into the same family, and it provides a list of *families* that each can provide a list of *fonts*.

But for font designers, those three axes were still too limiting. So, name IDs 16 / 17 might include family-internal distinctions that WPF / DWrite couldn't handle. And so name IDs 21 and 22 were added: if 16/17 include subfamily distinctions other than weight, stretch or style, then 21/22 strings should be added to present a family model in a WPF/DWrite-friendly way.

(Needless to say, font designers found it really annoying to have to get three separate pairs of family/sub-family strings right in their fonts.)

I won't go into detail, but there was something that came up early in Windows 10 involving font families for optical size variants. (Like Adobe's Kepler Pro family.) The long and short is, it lead to a question of whether *yet another* pair of name IDs would be needed to support a family model with weight, stretch, style *and* optical size as axes. Yikes! There must be a better way.

OK, now we come to 2016. Microsoft collaborated with Apple, Adobe, Google and others to develop an extension to OpenType known as *variable fonts*. (See [here](https://medium.com/variable-fonts/https-medium-com-tiro-introducing-opentype-variable-fonts-12ba6cd2369) and [here](https://uxdesign.cc/the-performance-benefits-of-variable-fonts-79af8c4ff56c) for some good reading on variable fonts.) Variable fonts allow the font designer to build in continuous variation in the design along *any number of axes of variation* within a single family.

Variable fonts implied that there would never be a need for proliferating more family/sub-family pairs of name IDs. (In fact, even 21/22 wouldn't be needed.) But that was because variable fonts basically force applications that want to support them to support the open-ended nature of name IDs 16/17, with families that can be as big and divers as the font designer wants them to be.

One other thing about variable fonts: because they support (near-)continuous design variation, you could ask for "Bold", or you could ask for *just-a-tiny-bit-bolder-then-bold*, or lots of other possibilities. Now, the font designer couldn't possibly give sub-family names to all possibilities (in principle, something like 2^14 possible variants on any axis). But they can choose particular instances to give names to. When it comes to enumerating variable fonts, you'll get an enumeration of the *named instances*. If you want, you can also get the detailed axis info (what axes and what numeric range for each axis).

### Enumerating name IDs 16/17

Now I can finally answer your questions: if you want to enumerate fonts as Adobe apps would, using name ID 16 for families, then use the [`IDWriteFactory7`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefactory7) interface to call the [`GetSystemFontCollection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nf-dwrite_3-idwritefactory7-getsystemfontcollection) method. Note that you'll need to choose a [`DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/ne-dwrite_3-dwrite_font_family_model) option:

- `DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL_WEIGHT_STRETCH_STYLE`: many font families only have sub-family members that fit within the weight/stretch/style model. For those fonts, you'll get a collection with family/font organized based on name IDs 16 and 17. But if a family has other kinds of design variants, like optical size, then DWrite will present the family organized based on name IDs 21 and 22.
- `DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL_TYPOGRAPHIC`: This will *always* present families organized based on name IDs 16 and 17. Just be aware: you might get lots of different kinds of sub-family distinctions that are not weight, stretch or style.

If you want to find out if the font is a variable font and, if it is, get the axis details, there are other APIs for doing that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is full of invaluable information.